# Fullscreen and auto-height on second element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement an image box in HTML5/CSS3 showing an image and its description underneath in a fullscreen lightbox. The problem I have is that I would like the description at the bottom of the screen to have a dynamic height (i.e. I don't want the description to be cut) and the image to take the remaining space, constrained to a max-width and max-height of 100% of the remaining space.

My problem is a bit similar to the "dynamic-height sticky-footer" problem,
except that the whole content should always have 100% height, no more, no less.

I've tried to solve the problem with a "table-row technique" because of the dynamic height: see http://galengidman.com/2014/03/25/responsive-flexible-height-sticky-footers-in-css/ for an explanation. However I can't make it work. Either the large image makes the table grow out of bounds or I can't force the description to "take" its height *before* the image. See my fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/sprat/ho463toa/

```
.content {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed; /* does not work with, does not work without either */
}

.image-area {
  display: table-row;
  height: 1px;
}

.description-area {
  display: table-row;
  height: auto;
}
```

So I need some help. I'm looking for a pure CSS solution if it's possible. Maybe that's something that can be done with a flexbox but I'm a little bit concerned about the browser support. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use flexbox for the layout. With prefixes it supports IE10+.

It uses background image instead of inline image.

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/mh545La9/)**

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { margin: 0; }
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
.fullscreen {
  position: fixed;
  left: 20px; right: 20px; top: 20px; bottom: 20px;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.image-area {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
}
.image-area:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background: url('//dummyimage.com/1000') center / cover;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
}
.description-area {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullscreen">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="image-area">
      <!-- <img src="http://img0.mxstatic.com/wallpapers/f424924e12f269c3dfd65e5be8cda9ba_large.jpeg"> -->
    </div>
    <div class="description-area">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec congue et ante id sodales. Etiam mollis neque nisi, id maximus tellus condimentum a. Duis condimentum erat quis ligula maximus mollis. Morbi congue, nunc sit amet suscipit consectetur,
        enim tortor lobortis felis, eget aliquam sem tortor quis augue. Duis ac viverra urna, non scelerisque leo. Nam vel dolor risus. Duis feugiat vulputate neque id fermentum. Aenean rhoncus libero ipsum, commodo vulputate dui commodo a. Maecenas sit
        amet pulvinar orci. Proin dapibus dui vel justo vulputate, a aliquam dui rhoncus. Phasellus lacinia venenatis leo, vel facilisis lorem. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Integer erat ipsum, pharetra
        ac tempor et, viverra et nibh.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Useful links:

- http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox
- https://autoprefixer.github.io/

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't see how it solves my problem: the description is not fully shown in all cases, a scrollbar appear.

Comment: Also, there's a big number of browser bugs around flex support, that's why I would like to avoid using flexboxes if possible.

Comment: I have made an edit, please check it out. Tested on Chrome and Firefox all works fine. Tried table but couldn't get it.